# unity sound Effect wont Play

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

```
IEnumerator waitDead()
{
    yield return new WaitForSeconds(0.85f);
    CanvasToDisable.SetActive(false);
    CanvasToDisable2.SetActive(false);
    FindObjectOfType<gameUI>().enableExitScene();
    Destroy(gameObject);
}

public void playerDeath()
{
    deathSound.Play();
    isHit = true;
    animator.SetBool("isCrouching", false);
    animator.SetBool("isSitting", false);
    animator.SetBool("isJumping", false);
    animator.SetBool("isDead", true);
    StartCoroutine(waitDead());
    rb.velocity = new Vector2(0f, 0f);
    timerStart = false;
}
```

[image: audio informations]

so I got my jump and crouch sound of the player to work but not my Death Sound on player hit. I tried several things and still don't know how to fix this issues. I shared my code and a ss of the unity audio, thanks for reading and helping!

Comment: Please update your tags. `unityscript` is deprecated and this question is not related to `visual-studio`. Next time when you add tags, think about what you are tagging really matters to the question at hand.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need yo use Audio Source for playing a death sound. Audio Source can be used mainly for background music etc. What you can do is using a *Audio Clip*. Here is an example;

```
//Get the audio that you want to play
[SerializeField] AudioClip DeathSound;
//Adjust the volume of the audio as you wish
[SerializeField] float FltDeathSoundVolume = 0.5f;
```

Then in the method that you want to play the audio, play it like this;

```
AudioSource.PlayClipAtPoint(DeathSound, Camera.main.transform.position, FltDeathSoundVolume);
```

This way, you can play the audio near the main camera, which will make the audio sound at better quality.